# Junit4 won't launch any activity

Tags: android, junit4

I had a problem with Junit4 UI tests on Android. They compiled fine but they didn't launch any activity.

Problem was, that my device suports multi-"space" (more users each with own space).

Answer (score 0):

The problem was solved by deleting the second space.

(Xaiomi Redmi Note 7)